# No generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, lambda, expression

I'm writing some code that will modify an expression so that the subquery contained in it will get ordered.

I found a similar piece of code [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1379693/509464), but it's not working for me. I also tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892605/cant-find-orderby-on-queryable-with-the-supplied-arguments) answer, but I'm not able to apply this to my piece of code

> No generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

```
MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "OrderBy"/*Descending*/,
    new Type[] { typeof(TSource), filterpart.OrderOverPropertyGetterValueType },
    navigationalProperty.Body,
    filterpart.OrderOverPropertyGetter);
```

I'm trying to figure out which of the 2 type parameters or 2 other arguments is causing this error.

- `OrderOverPropertyGetterValueType` is just `typeof(DateTime)` in this
  case
- `TSource` is an Entity Type (`Gifts`)
- `navigationalProperty.Body` contains {`source.Gifts.AsQueryable()`} with expression type: `System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression`
- `filterpart.OrderOverPropertyGetter` contains `{g => g.Date}` with expression type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Gift,System.DateTime>>`

I'm clueless how to diagnose which of the four parameters is incorrect. I'm thinking one of the expression types may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My type definitions were wrong, as the error suggested.

`typeof(TSource)` had to be `typeof(TNav)`, since we are ordering `source.Gifts`.

Comment: Where is TNav defined at?  what is it?

Comment: Please provide more detail for your answer. I got a scenario where sorting needed to be done using simple as well as navigational property through a grid

Comment: TNav is the type of the navigational property.