# Generate sorted list using expression tree

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection which is of type IQueryable, I need to sort this based on some dynamic sort fields. Sort fields are inside a list.

I write the following method to do this.

```
public List<T> Order<T>(IQueryable<T> source, List<string> propertyNames)
    {

        if(propertyNames != null && propertyNames.Count > 0)
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), string.Empty);
            var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyNames[0]);

            var sort = Expression.Lambda(property, param);
            MethodCallExpression orderByCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),"OrderBy",new[] { property.Type },Expression.Quote(sort));
            if(propertyNames.Count > 1)
            {
                foreach(var item in propertyNames)
                {
                    param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), string.Empty);
                    property = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, item);

                    sort = Expression.Lambda(property, param);

                    orderByCall = Expression.Call(
                        typeof(Queryable),
                        "ThenBy", new[] { typeof(T), property.Type },
                        orderByCall,
                        Expression.Quote(sort));
                }
            }

            var results = (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(orderByCall);
            if(results != null)
             return results.ToList();

        }

        return null;
    }
```

when I executed  `MethodCallExpression orderByCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),"OrderBy",new[] { property.Type },Expression.Quote(sort));` I got some exception

> No generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is
>   compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type
>   arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943024/no-generic-method-orderby-on-type-queryable-is-compatible-with-the-supplied

Comment: unrelated: `if(propertyNames?.Count > 0)`

Comment: Also, must this really be done on the `IQueryable`  (i.e., before the query is sent to the database)?  If the sorting can be done on an IList (i.e., after it comes back from the database), this gets easier.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have a direct solution for your error.

Here is an alternative ("kept it simple") approach to dynamically order your data.

1) Add these extension methods somewhere in your project

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TProperty>(this IQueryable<TSource> source
      , Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> expression, bool descending)
{
      return !descending ? source.OrderBy(expression) : source.OrderByDescending(expression);
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> ThenBy<TSource, TProperty>(this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source
  , Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> expression, bool descending)
{
  return !descending ? source.ThenBy(expression) : source.ThenByDescending(expression);
}
```

2) Now you can just loop your list of property names and apply the OrderBy / ThenBy on your IQueryable.

Other idea: you could adapt your method so it accepts expressions instead of property name strings.